# What RegEx would clean up this set of inputs?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string

I'm trying to figure out a RegEx that would match the following:

`.../string-with-no-spaces` -> `string-with-no-spaces`

**or**

`string-with-no-spaces:...` -> `string-with-no-spaces`

**or**

`.../string-with-no-spaces:...` -> `string-with-no-spaces`

where ... can be anything in these example strings:

```
example.com:8080/string-with-no-spaces:latest
string-with-no-spaces:latest
example.com:8080/string-with-no-spaces
string-with-no-spaces
```

and a bonus would be

```
http://example.com:8080/string-with-no-spaces:latest
```

and all would match `string-with-no-spaces`.

Is it possible for a single RegEx to cover all those cases?

So far I've gotten as far as `/\/.+(?=:)/` but that not only includes the slash, but only works for case 3. Any ideas?

Edit: Also I should mention that I'm using Node.js, so ideally the solution should pass all of these: https://jsfiddle.net/ys0znLef/

Comment: Is there anything definitive that will always be there?

Comment: Only 'string-with-no-spaces'. If knew RegEx and could translate the RegEx I need to English, it would be "Remove http:// if it's there, then remove everything before a slash if there is one, then remove everything after a colon if there is one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
(?:.*/)?([^/:\s]+)(?::.*|$)
```

Comment: Missing an escape character and it still matches a whitespace.

Comment: @SteveKline: What escape character? The negated character class make sure we haven'tany spaces in the string. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @rock321987 Was just going to say the same. To clarify, the expression should ideally pass all these tests: https://jsfiddle.net/ys0znLef/

Comment: Maybe my question was a bit vague, but essentially I need an exp that will take any of those inputs and match anything in place of "string-with-no-spaces".

Comment: Also, the string definitely has no spaces, so it's ok if the exp breaks in cases where it does because that will never happen.

Comment: Doesn't match the last one, string-with-no-spaces

Comment: @SteveKline: Yes it does!

Comment: Seems like JS doesn't support some of the magic in here too. Gives some strange outputs: https://jsfiddle.net/337f3xyw/

Comment: That was my point but I wasn't going to tell him why it was inaccurate :)

Comment: @Paraknight: The matched string is in group 1 (ie. matches[1] in your jsfiddle), not in group 0

Answer (score 1):

Here's the expression I've got... just trying to tweak to use the slash but not include it.

Updated result works in JS

```
\S([a-zA-Z0-9.:/\-]+)\S
//works on regexr, regex storm, & regex101 - tested with a local html file to confirm JS matches strings

var re = /\S([a-zA-Z0-9.:/\-]+)\S/;
```

Comment: Seems like JS doesn't support everything in there. I get three different matches across the test cases: https://jsfiddle.net/zd6s50e9/ Also I see a "com" in there; I forgot to mention that the TLD could be anyting. Maybe one test case should be .org or so.

Comment: Updated my results - matches all 5 cases

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following solution using specific regex pattern and `String.match` function:

```
var re = /(?:[/]|^)([^/:.]+?)(?:[:][^/]|$)/,
    // (?:[/]|^) - passive group, checks if the needed string is preceded by '/' or is at start of the text
    // (?:[:][^/]|$) - passive group, checks if the needed string is followed by ':' or is at the end of the text
    searchString = function(str){
        var result = str.match(re);
        return result[1];
    };

console.log(searchString("example.com:8080/string-with-no-spaces"));
console.log(searchString("string-with-no-spaces:latest"));
console.log(searchString("string-with-no-spaces"));
console.log(searchString("http://example.com:8080/string-with-no-spaces:latest"));
```

The output for all the cases above will be `string-with-no-spaces`

Comment: Brilliant! Could you break down what's going on there just so I understand it a bit more? How come it's result[1]? And from what I can see, sometimes result.length can be pretty high too.

Comment: @Paraknight added some explanation. Besides, don't worry about `result.length`, it will always be `2` in all cases

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your explanation but just realised that @Toto beat you to it and I didn't realise it, so that's the reason I accepted their answer instead of yours.